# Installing nodejs: I need GNU make. Please run 'gmake' instead

Tags: node.js, freebsd

I want to install nodejs on my PCBSD 10 system. I have downloaded the src file of latest nodejs. On terminal I ran the command `./configure` It runs fine. After that I tried `make` but its asking on console

```
I need GNU make. Please run 'gmake' instead.
```

Then I tried `gmake` the terminal says

```
CORRECT>gmake (y | n | e | a)?
```

I pressed y then again it says "I need GNU make. Please run gmake instead"

How to install nodejs???

Comment: Looks like your shell is `tcsh`. If you run `sh`, then type `gmake`, what happens? If `gmake` is not found, you need to install it. It may be in a package on your installation media, or if you have the ports system installed you can do 'cd /usr/ports/devel/gmake;make;make install`

Answer (score 0):

If you install it using the FreeBSD ports system, that will take care of these details for you.

If you haven't installed the ports tree, run the following command as root;

```
svnlite checkout https://svn0.us-west.FreeBSD.org/ports/head /usr/ports
```

Note that there are some [subversion mirrors for FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/svn.html). Choose the one closest to you. After the initial checkout, you can update the ports tree by running the following command as root;

```
svnlite update /usr/ports |& less
```

When the ports tree is installed and up-to-date, you can install node by running the following commands as root:

```
cd /usr/ports/www/node
make install clean
```

This will first install the ports that node depends on (gmake and python2) and then node itself.

You might also want to install the node package manager from the `www/npm` port.